# How to pass function to other component with react-native-router-flux(RNRF)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am making react-native android app now.
my code is like below

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.goToSearchComponent = this.goToSearchComponent.bind(this);
}

goToSearchComponent() {
    Actions.search({handleSearch: this.handleSearch});
}
...
```

Action.search() function works good, so I can see search component.

But in search component, 'this.props.handleSearch' is 'undefined'.

For test, I use code like below...

```
Action.search( {textText: 'hmm'} )
```

this works good too.. (in search component, this.props.textText = 'hmm')...

How to pass function to other component with react-native-router-flux(RNRF)?

Comment: Have you binded the handleSearch function in the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to bind the function call like this?

```
Actions.search({handleSearch: this.handleSearch.bind(this)});
```

Comment: Thanks @Wanda you just saved my time.